# How to prove that $W=U_1 \oplus(U_2 \cap W)$ if $U_1 \subseteq W$, given that $V=U_1 \oplus U_2$ and $U_1,U_2,W$ are subspaces of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

> Prove that $W=U_1 \oplus(U_2 \cap W)$ if $U_1 \subseteq W$, given that $V=U_1 \oplus U_2$ and $U_1,U_2,W$ are vector subspaces of $V$.

Here's what I have:

Let $U_1=Sp(S), U_2=Sp(T)$.

Because $U_1 \subseteq W$ then there exists a set of vectors {$x$} such that $U_1 \cup \{x\}=W.$

Then:
$$
Sp(S) \cup \{x\} =Sp(S) \oplus(Sp(T) \cap(Sp(S) \cup \{x\}))\\
=Sp(S) \oplus (\{0\} \cup \{x\})\quad (*)\\
=Sp(S)+\{x\}
$$

(*) because $V=U_1 \oplus U_2$ then $Sp(S) \cap Sp(T)=\{0\}$

At this point I'm stuck because {$x$} is a subset of vectors not a subspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use the definition of the direct sum.

The assumptions may be rewritten as:

a) 
 any element of $V$ is the sum of an element of $U_1$ and an element of $U_2$.

b) The intersection of $U_1$ and $U_2$ is the null vector.

Now you want to prove to things:

1) any element of $W$ is the sum of an element of $U_1$ and an element of $U_2\cap W$.

2) The intersection of $U_1$ and $U_2\cap W$ is the null vector.

It seems pretty clear how to proceed now. You will need the assumption $U_1\subset W$ to get 1) from a).

Comment: is this enough to prove that any element of $W$ is the sum of an element $U_1$ and an element $U_2 \cap W$: because $U_1 \subseteq W$ and $U_2 \cap W \subseteq W$ and because $W$ is the subspace of $V$ and $V$ is composed of $U_1$ and $U_2$ then there're no other elements in $V$ that $W$ can get?

Comment: Try to write an exhaustive proof, and you will see where you will need the assmption. I cannot tell you more than I already did, otherwise I would solve your exercise...

Your proof should start with: let $w\in W$. In particular, $w\in V$, so...

Comment: How about this try: in order to prove that $W$ is a direct sum first we need to prove that $W=U_1+(U_2 \cap W)=Sp(U_1 \cup (U_2 \cap W))=Sp(V \cap W)=Sp(W)=W$

Comment: Then we also need to prove that $U_1\cap (U_2 \cap W)=0$. But $U_2 \cap W \in U_2$ so the intersection is always an empty set.

Comment: Certainly not an empty set. A vector space is never empty. And you should write your argument in such a way it explictely says where you use the hypotheses.

For the other part, it cannot be right, since you are starting from the conclusion. I told you what to use,  where you want to go, and how to start...i cannot do more apart from solving your exercise for you...

Comment: I didn't say that $W$ is an empty set, rather $U_1 \cap (U_2 \cap W)$ is an empty set or contains only the zero vector

Comment: Once again, $U_1\cap(U_2\cap W)$ cannot be empty!! it's a vector space !

Comment: But the intersection contains only the zero vector?

Comment: Well, this is your homework. Write down a proof (a real one, not vague arguments). For the third time, look at the hypotheses a) and b) in my first message, and look at assertions 1) and 2) you want to prove. The path from one to another is not very long.

Comment: can You suggest a way to prove that $W$ is a direct sum of $U_1$ and $W/cap U_2$. I’m stuck