# Given three sub-spaces $U, U_1, U_2$ of $V$, how can I prove that $U=U_1 + (U\cap U_2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a $n$-dimensional vector space and $U,U_1,U_2$ are sub-spaces of $V$. Also $V = U_1 \oplus U_2$ and $U_1 \subset U$.

How do you show that $U = U_1 + (U\cap U_2)$?

I need some help showing $u\in U \implies u\in U_1 + (U\cap U_2)$, so $U\subseteq U_1+(U\cap U_2)$. Showing the other way around was quite easy but could someone help me with the above implication?

(The same question was actually answered several years ago: [How to prove that $W=U_1 \oplus(U_2 \cap W)$ if $U_1 \subseteq W$, given that $V=U_1 \oplus U_2$ and $U_1,U_2,W$ are subspaces of $V$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2302514/1155685))

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.se. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof goes like this:

Let $v \in U$ be a vector in $U$. Then it must also be in $V$, which means it can be expressed as $v = u_1 + u_2$ where $u_1$ and $u_2$ belong to $U_1$ and $U_2$, respectively. However, note that $u_1 + u_2$ must still be in $U$, so $u_1, u_2 \in U$. This is only the case when $u_2 \in U \cap U_2$. Therefore we have proved that

$
U \subseteq U_1 + U \cap U_2
$

Now consider the following identities:

$
\dim(V) = \dim(U) + \dim(U_2) - \dim(U \cap U_2)
$

$
\dim(V) = \dim(U_1) + \dim(U_2)
$

If you substitute the second equation in the first one you get that $\dim(U) = \dim(U_1) + \dim(U \cap U_2)$. Therefore it must be indeed true that $U = U_1 + U \cap U_2$.

Comment: That’s very cool! I forgot about that identity for sub-spaces. I showed $v\in U_1+(U\cap U_2)\implies v\in U$ first so I could’ve just used that identity and be done. :D Thank you!

Comment: By the way, there are two little typos where you wrote $\cup$ instead of $\cap$.

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you Hahaha. I'll edit that.